# Characterizations of Real Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

For functions over a finite field $F$ with prime cardinality and $|F|>2d$ you have the characterization that $p$ is a degree $d$ polynomial if and only if $\sum_{i=0}^{d+1} (-1)^{i+1}{d+1 \choose i} p(a+ib) = 0$ for every $a,b \in F^n$.

Does any similar characterization of the functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or even $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) which are polynomials exist?

The only characterization that I am aware of is that if $f$ is infinitely differentiable and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ then $f$ is a polynomial.

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Infinitely differentially? Assuming you meant "differentiable" doesn't $e^x$ satisfy it as well?

Comment: @crystal_math yes, you are correct. I omitted the additional condition that the derivative needs to converge to a constant

Comment: I wouldn't say, for example, that $xy+z$ is a degree 1 polynomial but I suppose you could.

Comment: @user10354138 good, thank you. I should not have chosen F2. If the characteristic is larger (>2d should be sufficient) then this will work.

Comment: The problem goes deeper than that.  Since you are only looking at $p$ elements $a+b\mathbb{F}_p$ even when you are really looking at $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}^n\to\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, every function is a polynomial of degree $\leq p-1$ by your definition for all $k,n,p$.

Comment: Ah whoops sorry about that, it should work if you add that it is a prime field